# Is there a way to itirate through mulitple array using a for loop in BASH

Tags: arrays, bash

I have 4 arrays:

```
ARRAY1=( A B C D )
ARRAY2=( E F G )
ARRAY3=( H I J K L M )
ARRAY4=( N )
```

Some how I would like to get a new array with these elements in it:

```
FINAL_ARRAY=( ARRAY1 A ARRAY1 B ARRAY1 C ARRAY1 D ARRAY2 E ARRAY2 F ARRAY2 G ARRAY3 H ARRAY3 I ARRAY3 J ARRAY3 K ARRAY3 L ARRAY3 M ARRAY4 N )
```

Can this be done using some kind of for loop or any other way in BASH?

Thanks.

Comment: You really shouldn't be turning variable names (code) into data.  Do you make a habit of putting your C variable names in C string values too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
ARRAY1=( A B C D )
ARRAY2=( E F G )
ARRAY3=( H I J K L M )
ARRAY4=( N )
ARRAYNAMES=(ARRAY1 ARRAY2 ARRAY3 ARRAY4)
for an in "${ARRAYNAMES[@]}"; do
    aref="$an[@]"
    for item in "${!aref}"; do
        NEWARRAY=("${NEWARRAY[@]}" "$an" "$item")
    done
done
echo "${NEWARRAY[@]}"
```

*Output:*

```
ARRAY1 A ARRAY1 B ARRAY1 C ARRAY1 D ...
```

Comment: bang on. That's it. Thanks a ton perreal. I wasted entire day for this. at the end, so simple.

Comment: You need to at least quote your expansions better.  "${NEWARRAY[@]}"

Comment: @perreal: also $an, $item.